# Trying moving arm using cartesian waypoints

Tags: ros, moveit

I am trying to move my arm using providing Cartesian way-points. I am generating Cartesian way points and feeding the arm to move on those using moveit. When I try to move it using only position values in x, y and z it moves, or only Quaternions values it moves, but when I try to move the arm using both it does not move. I am new to ROS and MoveIt, any suggestion will be much appreciated.

This is the output of Moveit CMD which is controlling the arm

[ INFO] [1700662816.457442469]: Received request to compute Cartesian path
[ INFO] [1700662816.457947331]: Attempting to follow 2 waypoints for link 'link_tcp' using a step of 0.005000 m and jump threshold 0.000000 (in global reference frame)

Comment: Is this the *only* output of the command? I'd be willing to bet the reason nothing is moving is because moveit cannot solve the requested trajectory, and it would likely be outputting a warning or error if that's the case. The position or orientation is valid, but this doesn't guarantee that their combination will be.

Comment: @cst0 there is no warning on any command window that's why I am confused. Regarding the complexity even it it has to just move in z , it does not given both orientations and position.

Comment: If the arm has the ability to move with this pipeline (which you've shown that it does), and the only thing that's changed is the goal state, then the goal state is almost certainly the problem.